# When we call Abort() method in Threading,and For conditions? Is there any validations to check before Abort the thread?

Tags: c#

I'm getting `ThreadAbortException` when call `Abort()` method, and I referred to solve this in Stack Overflow that they said to use `Thread.ResetAbort()` method before ending the thread, but It's not clear to me.

Please suggest me where can I use `ResetAbort` method. I'm getting that exception in marked line when call the `Abort()` method.

```
while (true)
{
    Group g = null;
    if (countGroupsList != null)
    {
        lock (countGroupsList.SyncRoot) // Exception here
        {
            if (groupsCounter < countGroupsList.Count)
            {
                g = (Group)countGroupsList[groupsCounter];
                groupsCounter++;
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: `Thread.Abort()` is a bad idea and generally means you have other issues with your solution. Why do you need to exit the thread this way?

Comment: what is the way of stop the thread?

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Abort` is a rude way to kill a thread. But if you really want to do so you can just ignore the exception. It's the way the thread says: Ouch, I'm dying.

You also can catch this exception and use the `Thread.Abort` method in your catch block. But that will prevent the thread to be killed.